# how to mock socket.io-client with vue-socket.io-extended using vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vue-test-utils

this is how I integrate socket io client from vue main.js

```
import socketIoExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended'
import socketIo from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.use(socketIoExt, socketIo('http://192.168.1.1:8000'));
```

code below is one of my example function for requesting API

```
getUserInfo(user_id){
   console.log("before request")
   this.$socket.emit('userInfo', user_id, (err,res) => {
      console.log("inside the request API")
      return err ? err : res
   })
}
```

here's the package versions:

```
"socket.io-client": "^4.1.2"
"vue-socket.io-extended": "^3.2.1"
```

I use vue cli 2

question: how can I mock this API using vue test utils?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock $socket object while mounting component, like this

```
const createComponent = (propsData: componentPropsType) => (mount<Component>(
    Component, {
        propsData,
        mocks: {
            $socket: {
                client: {
                    disconnected: false,
                    connected: false,
                },
                connect: jest.fn(),
                disconnect: jest.fn(),
            },
        },
    },
));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).